# Change background color of header row for element-ui

Tags: css, vue.js, element-ui

I am using `element-ui` for adding a table with some data in a Vue project. I wish to change the background color only for the header row. How can I achieve that?

Things I've tried:

Added a custom class to `:row-class-name` prop:

```html
<el-table :row-class-name="headerStyle">
```

(In methods)

```
headerStyle() {
   return 'customClass'
}
```

In style tags in the same `.vue` file:

```
.el-table .customClass {
/*Custom CSS*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the table header's `background` with the [`header-cell-style`](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes) prop:

```html
<el-table :header-cell-style="{ background: 'blue' }">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zYKqGdy)

Or you could apply a style to a class name specified by `header-cell-class-name`:

```html
<el-table header-cell-class-name="my-header">

<style>
.my-header {
  background: blue !important; // !important needed here to override default style
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the single column,The following code maybe can help you

```
        <el-table-column
        label='address' prop='address'  align='center'
      >
        <template #header="{ column }">
          <div :style="{ background: '#f2f2f2', color: 'blue' }">
            {{ column.label }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
```

(i'm learning English now.I would appreciate it if you can point out my expresssion problem )